# "docker search" returns far fewer results in bash than on hub.docker.com

Tags: docker

I learned that I can "docker search docuwiki" in my terminal to search an image on Docker Hub. For a popular application, this returns a mere 3 hits, none of which seemingly from a well-known source. On the other hand, when I go to hub.docker.com and use their GUI to perform a search on "docuwiki", I was told there are 286 hits, and the top results are from bitnami etc. When I tried to `docker pull bitnami/docuwiki:latest`, I was told "Error response from daemon: pull access denied for bitnami/docuwiki, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'". Of course, I logged in (again) and that didn't do the trick. What might be the reason?

Comment: See https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/dokuwiki, it's `bitnami/dokuwifi`, not `bitnami/docuwifi`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @atline pointed out, I searched the wrong thing... should be "dokuwiki", not "docuwiki".